# asp hyperlinkfield confirmation message

Tags: html, asp.net, hyperlink

I have to add confirmation message on hyperlink like "Are you sure you what to that?" But I'm seeing asp first time in my life and spend last three hours on google but cant find good example to use. Any ideas?

This is how it looks right now:

### [image]

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="data" 
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SMSReport.aspx?data={0}&amp;db=1" 
                    HeaderText="Ataskaita" Text="Ataskaita" />
```

Comment: The "are you sure" thing is normally a client-side thing and therefore should be handled with Javascript, not with server-side code... but I've got the feeling you won't have a clue what I'm talking about neither...

Comment: well there is two files one is sms.aspx and the other is SMS.aspx.vb. So i think sms.aspx is client-side. Or i'm wrong?

Comment: You just confirmed my feeling. Before programming for web, you need to understand a bit how it works. aspx is server-side, with a also server-side codebehind page xxx.aspx.vb, client-side code is HTML + CSS + Javascript

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make button, styled like link and redirect with javascript.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnRedirect" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="White" Text="link" OnClientClick="return Redirect();"/>


    function Redirect() {
        return confirm('Are u sure?');
    }
```

If you want to work in grid column you can do something like

```
<<Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnRedirect" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="White" Text="link" OnClientClick="return Redirect();" OnClick="btnRedirect_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("YourUrl")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
```

And Code behind "*.aspx.vb" file `protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect((sender as Button).CommandArgument);
        }`

Comment: I think something is wrong. Its not working when i try to replace. Maybe because its in '<Columns>' and '<asp:GridView ID="GridView5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" '. I mean because its in GridView?

Comment: Should i add new library into *.aspx.vb? Because its not working in .aspx.vb when I add. All other functions are  'Protected Sub'.

Comment: No i gave you example with C# but you using VB (they have many common things) in VB event should be something like Protected Sub btnRedirect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs){
 Dim btn = CType(sender, Button)
        Response.Redirect(btn.CommandArgument); }